# Solving particular integral $R(x)$ has $a^x$ term.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am supposed to solve the below differential equation question.
$$
\left(D^2+4\right) y = \cosh(2x - 1) + 3^x
$$

I am not aware of a case where $R(x)$ has a term of form $a^x$. How should I proceed from here?

Comment: What is $R(x)$?

Comment: @KentaS perhaps that's the notation they use for the RHS of the ODE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, solve the homogeneous one first and then try a linear combination of $\sinh, \cosh$ and $3^x$ for a particular solution.

Note that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left[a^x\right]
 = \frac{d}{dx} \left[e^{x \ln a}\right]
 = e^{x \ln a} \ln a 
 = a^x \ln a.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I never though of writing $a^x$ as $e^{x lna}$. Solved the problem.

Comment: Please read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @amWhy could you explain what other changes you would like the OP to make according to the new standards. It is pretty obvious this was a homework question of some sort, that does not need to be explicitly stated. He does explain that he has never seen this form before, which makes him trying things rather irrelevant -- so I suggested for him to do try the real form and explained why you would do that. From his comment above seems like he understood the concept, so learning also took place. What is lacking in this process from the point of view of the new standards? Thanks

Comment: @amWhy also is there standard (meta?) chat where I could place a question like this so people explain this to me if you are not available? thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

$$(D^2+4)y_p=3^x$$
$$(D^2+4)y_p=e^{\ln 3x}$$
Note that $(u=\ln 3 x)$:
$$D=\dfrac {d}{dx}=\dfrac {d}{d \ln 3 x}\dfrac {d \ln 3 x
}{dx}=\ln 3\dfrac {d}{du} $$
So that the DE becomes:
$$(\ln^2 3D^2+4)y_p=e^{u}$$
$$y_p=\dfrac {1}{\ln^23 D^2+4}e^u=\dfrac {e^u}{\ln^23+4}$$
$$ \implies y_p=\dfrac {3^x}{\ln^23+4}$$

Comment: Please read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.